# check the existence of a number or greater without using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, max

I have a dictionary like:

```
chars_dict = {'a' : 1, 'c': 2, 'e': 4, 'h': 3, 's': 1}
```

Simply this dictionary will have characters and their counts with minimum being 1 and maximum being dependent on the characters in the string.

Now, I want to check for existence of count ***2 or greater*** without using `for` loop. To achieve this, I reversed the above dictionary. Now the dictionary becomes,

```
 rev_chars_dict = {1: ['a', 's'], 2: 'c', 4: 'e', 3: 'h'}
```

But, how can I check for the existence of keys (here numbers 2 or greater than that) without using `for` loop? Is there a pythonic way of doing it?

I would like something like,

```
if >=2 in rev_chars_dict:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: So a comprehension does not count as a for loop?

Comment: Your values are not unique, so when you swap them with your keys, you're going to close some entries (because `dict` keys are unique)

Comment: Sorry, in that case let's assume I have list of chars as values after reversing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a for loop? Is this a homework problem?

```
max(d.values()) >= 2
```

where `d` is the dictionary.

Comment: This is great! So, I guess I don't even have to reverse the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Find the keys over 1:

```
[key for key, value in chars_dict.items() if value >1]
```

for a simple test:

```
len([key for key, value in chars_dict.items() if value >1])>0
```

Comment: Thansk! But still, the list comprehension sort of uses `for` loop